# Magento looks for my custom local module under namespace Mage

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

I've created a custom module with an Observer to log every product change on a log file.
The Observer is listening on the event `catalog_product_save_after`.
I've created the folder for my namespace under `app/code/local` and so I defined it on the configuration files.

My problem is that Magento is trying to load the module under the namespace Mage, and I don't know the reason for this behavior.

Here are the error log:

> 2018-01-05T09:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Mynamespace/Editlog/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> 2018-01-05T09:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Mynamespace/Editlog/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/local:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/community:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/core:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/lib:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/lib/php')  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Does anyone know why is looking for the observer under the Mage directory ?
Do I have to put there my module?

Comment: Do you have a `config.xml` in the `etc/` folder of your module? Do you also have a properly formatted `Mynamespace_Editlog.xml` file in `app/etc/modules/`?

Comment: In your config you can specify your codePool, make sure it is set to `local`.

Comment: Yes I have this two files properly formatted, and the codePool is set to local

Comment: Could you add the config files to the post so we have some more information to go off, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I made a mistake on the config.xml:
I didn't define the models tag.

After I defined it, the module is loaded correctly.

The next time I will also post the whole configuration files.

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing the following line in config.xml from:

```
<class>[modulename]/observer</class>
```

to:

```
<class>Mynamespace_Editlog_Model_Observer</class>
```

Comment: Changing to full class name makes it impossible to rewrite the observer.